# Не получается отправить файл на сервер

Tags: php, java, android, клиент-сервер

Android:

```
    public void onClickSend(View view) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
    }

        private class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        HttpURLConnection conn;
        Integer res;

        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                File file = new File(mFilePath);

                HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.post("http://potatosing.16mb.com");
                request.part("image", "image.jpg", file);

                URL url = new URL(request.body());
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(1000000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                conn.connect();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return res;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri photoUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            mFilePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            new ConnectToServer().execute();
        }
    }
```

И сам сервер на php (index.php):

```
<?php 
    $uploaddir = 'files/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
?>
```

Вроде ошибки никакой android и не выдает, но файл почему то не сохраняется.

PS: я новичок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться примером с официального сайта php,  за одно проверите отправляется файл или нет.

```
<?php 

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/'; $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']); 

echo  "`<pre>`" ; if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n"; } else {
    echo "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n"; }

echo "Некоторая отладочная информация:"; print_r($_FILES);

print "`</pre>`";

?>
```

[код брал отсюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php)